# How to design a proper model in Keras for imbalanced multi-classification problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am solving imbalanced multi-classification (4 classes) problem with the sequential data. I prepared training and testing sets that contain the same number of records for each class:

- 100, 100, 100, 100 -> training set
- 20, 20, 20, 20 -> testing set

I get the following validation results of my LSTM Keras model. They are too bad. In the confusion matrix it can be seen that all records are classified as class 4.

```
****************************
| MODEL PERFORMANCE REPORT |
****************************
Average F1 score = 0.10.
Balanced accuracy score = 0.25.
Confusion matrix
[[ 0  0  0 20]
 [ 0  0  0 20]
 [ 0  0  0 20]
 [ 0  0  0 20]]
Other metrics
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00        20
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00        20
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00        20
           3       0.25      1.00      0.40        20

   micro avg       0.25      0.25      0.25        80
   macro avg       0.06      0.25      0.10        80
weighted avg       0.06      0.25      0.10        80
```

I don't want to proceed to hyper-parameters optimisation, because there seems to be something fundamentally wrong in my model.

I will appreciate so much if someone more experienced in LSTM and deep learning could point me my errors.

This is my data (I use a very small sample in order to experiment with a basic model that I will later train on a whole dataset):

```
400 train sequences
80 test sequences
X_train shape: (400, 20, 17)
X_test shape: (80, 20, 17)
y_train shape: (400, 4)
y_test shape: (80, 4)
```

This is my model and fit function:

```
hidden_neurons = 50
timestamps = 20
nb_features = 18

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
                units=hidden_neurons,
                return_sequences=True, 
                input_shape=(timestamps,nb_features),
                dropout=0.2, 
                recurrent_dropout=0.2
              )
         )

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units=nb_classes,
               activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics = ['accuracy'],optimizer='adadelta')

history = model.fit(np.array(X_train), y_train, 
                    validation_data=(np.array(X_test), y_test),
                    epochs=50,
                    batch_size=2,
                    callbacks=[model_metrics],
                    shuffle=False,
                    verbose=1)


class Metrics(Callback):

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.val_f1s = []
        self.val_recalls = []
        self.val_precisions = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        val_predict = np.argmax((np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))).round(), axis=1)
        val_targ = np.argmax(self.validation_data[1], axis=1)
        _val_f1 = metrics.f1_score(val_targ, val_predict, average='weighted')
        _val_recall = metrics.recall_score(val_targ, val_predict, average='weighted')
        _val_precision = metrics.precision_score(val_targ, val_predict, average='weighted')
        self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1)
        self.val_recalls.append(_val_recall)
        self.val_precisions.append(_val_precision)
        print(" — val_f1: {:f} — val_precision: {:f} — val_recall {:f}".format(_val_f1, _val_precision, _val_recall))
        return

model_metrics = Metrics()
```

[image]

[image]